# SQL LIKE operator in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If have this tables

```
USER TABLE
ID  | name  | mode
1   |  foo  | private

PRIVATE TABLE
private_id  | id |  private_name
1           | 1  |  private mode

PUBLIC TABLE
public_id   | id |  public_name
1           | 1  |  public mode
```

I want to return the query depending what data in school for example if the data of `COLUMN MODE` in `USER TABLE` is `private` I want it to search only in `PRIVATE TABLE` and if its `public` it only returns the data in `PUBLIC TABLE`

this is my code

```
if($search){
$search_str = '(user.name LIKE '%{$search}%'
                OR private.private_name LIKE '%{$search}%'
                OR public.public_name LIKE '%{search}%'
                )';
    $this->db->where($search_str,NULL,FALSE);

    $this->db->join("private","private.id = user.id","LEFT");
    $this->db->join("public","public.id = user.id","LEFT");
}
```

if my keyword is `mode` in search box it returns the `private mode` and `public mode`

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_str = '(user.name LIKE '%{$search}%'
                OR (private.private_name LIKE '%{$search}%' AND user.mode = 'private')
                OR (public.public_name LIKE '%{search}%' AND user.mode = 'public')
                )';
```

In this line `OR (private.private_name LIKE '%{$search}%' AND user.mode = 'private')` it will check the data in `MODE COLUMN` in `USER TABLE` if its equal to `private` and then proceed  to `PRIVATE TABLE` to find the specified pattern of a `keyword` in a `PRIVATE NAME COLUMN`.

And in this line `OR (public.public_name LIKE '%{$search}%' AND user.mode = 'public')` it will check the data in `MODE COLUMN` in `USER TABLE` if its equal to `public` and then proceed  to `PUBLIC TABLE` to find the specified pattern of a `keyword` in a `PUBLIC NAME COLUMN`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending the answer a bit more, for fellow programmers, to understand how it helped to solve the problem.

Comment: @Daenarys this is base as what I understand in my answer to my question